# Why does the list appear empty while trying to add nodes in the beginning?

Tags: java, oop, methods, nodes

I've literally lost my mind trying to figure out why my `add()` and `print()` methods won't work.  I've tried virtually everything but I just can't do this.  I know my code is dead wrong (I can't even tell if my code was right at one point or another because I deleted it to try new things) so what could be wrong with it?

I appreciate you taking the time to read.

NodeFN class:

```
public class NodeFN {
     private String data; // Data for node.
     private NodeFN next; // Next node.

public NodeFN(String data) {
    this.data = data; // Take the data value passed in & store it in the data field.
    this.next = null; // Take the next node & store it in the next field.
}

   // Mutator functions.
public String getData() {return data;}
public NodeFN getNext() {return next;}
public void setData(String d) {data = d;}
public void setNext(NodeFN n) {next = n;}
}
```

Queue class:

```
public class Queue {
   NodeFN head; // Head of node.
   public String n;

public Queue(String n) { 
    head = new NodeFN(n); // head is now an object of NodeFN which holds a string.
}

public void add(String n) {
    NodeFN nn = new NodeFN(n); // nn is now an object of NodeFN which holds a string, it should return something.
        if(head == null) {
            head = nn;
        }
        while(nn.getData().compareTo(head.getData()) < 0) {
                nn.setNext(head); // Put node in beginning of the list.
                nn.setData(n);      
        }
    }

public void print() {
    NodeFN nn = new NodeFN(n);

    while(nn != null) {
        nn.getNext().getData();
        System.out.println(nn.getData() + " ");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Queue q = new Queue("string to test");
    q.add("another string to test if add method works.");
    q.print();
}
}
```

Comment: What is the code output and what should it output?

Comment: It's output is nothing.  Nothing appears in the console.

Comment: @g24 Do you want to add all nodes passed into `add()` in the beginning?

Comment: @progy_rock Yeah I do.  I want the the strings that will be passed to the `add()` method (I want to be able to use `add()` method more than once) to be able to print to the console with the `print()` method whenever `print()` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak for your add method, but what is `n` here ?

```
public void print() {
    NodeFN nn = new NodeFN(n);

    while(nn != null) {
        nn.getNext().getData();
        System.out.println(nn.getData() + " ");
    }
}
```

The queue class should not care about `public String n` at all. You only need the `head` Node.

Then, `nn.getNext().getData();` is returning something, yes? But, you are not printing it nor are you "moving forward" in the list. (You don't assign `nn` to the next node).

Try something like this

```
public void print() {
    if (head == null) System.out.println("()");

    NodeFN tmp = head;

    while(tmp != null) {
        System.out.println(tmp.getData() + " ");
        tmp = tmp.getNext();
    }
}
```

---

If you want the nodes to be add at the start of the list, then this should work.

```
public void add(String n) {
    NodeFN nn = new NodeFN(n);
    if(head == null) {
        head = nn;
    }

    // Don't use a while loop, there is nothing to repeat
    if (n.compareTo(head.getData()) < 0) {
        // Both these operations put 'nn' in beginning of the list.
        nn.setNext(head); 
        head = nn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow.... I kid you not I had this EXACT same `add()` method code last night when I deleted it this morning because I thought it was wrong.  Of course, my `print()` method was way off so there was no way for me to see anything in the console to begin with.  Thanks a ton, cricket_007.

Comment: Welcome. Typically, I'd make a `toString` method instead of a void `print` method, but do what you want

Comment: I'm going to consider it, I think I see why you're saying that.  Thanks again, man.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a linked list. In order to print that, you need to loop through the list until you reach a null in `getNext()`. Essentially, you should end up with something like this:

```
public void print() {
   NodeFN current = head;

   while(current != null) {
       System.out.println(current.getData());
       current = current.getNext();
   }
}
```

As for your `add()` method, the idea is to basically put any new nodes as the `next` reference of the last node in your list. Simply keep a reference to the `last` node in your `Queue` class. When adding, set `next` of the `last` node to your newly created node, and set the new node as the `last`.

Answer (score 0):

For the add method, you had the right idea to start. Make `nn` the head if there are no element in the list yet. Otherwise, traverse the list to the last element and add it to the end (since it's a queue).

```
public void add(String n) {
    NodeFN nn = new NodeFN(n);
    if(head == null) {
        head = nn;
    }
    else {
        NodeFN cursor = this.head;
        while(cursor.getNext() != null) {
            cursor = cursor.getNext();
        }
        cursor.setNext(nn);
    }
}
```

If you want to add the new node to the beginning (for whatever strange reason), it would be even easier.

```
public void add(String n) {
    NodeFN nn = new NodeFN(n);
    nn.setNext(this.head);
    this.head = nn;
}
```

For the print method. You're not setting `nn` (the cursor) to reference any node in the actual queue. You should be setting `nn` to the head of the queue and then iterating through the queue. `NodeFN nn = this.head`. And then in the while loop's body, print the data `nn.getData()`, then move to the next node `nn = nn.getNext()`.

```
public void print() {
    NodeFN cursor= this.head;

    while(cursor != null) {
        System.out.println(cursor.getData() + " ");
        cursor= cursor.getNext();           
    }
}
```